# How do I send an email about Windows Update Failure

Tags: windows, windows-update, vmware, ansible

I have the below playbook which gathers information about only windows VM's from a `vcenter_inventory_vmware.yml` inventory file and executes the `ansible.windows.win_updates` module properly.  I am trying to trigger a handler that will send  an email notifying me when any of the 3 servers in my ansible-playbook command encounters a failure of any kind.  The handler is never triggered.  Can anyone tell me where my code needs to be modified?

ANSIBLE COMMAND:

```
ansible-playbook download_and_install_windows_updates.yml -l server1:server2:server3
```

download_and_install_windows_updates.yml

```
- hosts: windows

  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
  - name: Installing missing updates
    ansible.windows.win_updates:
      category_names:
        - Application
        - Connectors
        - Critical Updates
        - Definition Updates
        - Developer Kits
        - Feature Packs
        - Guidance
        - Security Updates
        - Service Packs
        - Tools
        - Update Rollups
        - Updates
        - Upgrade
      reject_list:
        - Security Intelligence Update for Microsoft Defender Antivirus
        - Update for Microsoft Defender Antivirus antimalware platform
        - Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool x64
      state: installed
      reboot: true
      reboot_timeout: 6300
    register: updates
    notify: Email
    when: ansible_failed_result.rc != 0

  handlers:
  - name: Email
    mail:
      host: <my company smtp server>
      port: 25
      to: (my email address>
      subject: "Playbook Failed"
      body: "Your playbook has failed. Please check the logs."
    delegate_to: localhost
```

Comment: Do you have any playbook that is able to send an email.  If your playbook does not send an email, I would first look your email configuration, to make sure it is correct. [Documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/mail_module.html)

Comment: Yes.  The email portion of the playbook works.

Comment: Then I am confused by what exactly is not working

Comment: you might want `changed_when` vs `when` to trigger `notify` this way if the update module failing doesn't create a changed result. Is the play actually returning a non-zero return code? The `win_updates` module has some other return values like `failed_update_count` that may be useful. You can also set something like `log_path: C:\ansible_wu.txt` to see what's going on

Comment: Please make updates to your situation by editing your question. Comments are mostly for people communicating with you, or for simple clarifying questions on your own part for those communicating with you. New and further information should be added to your question to make it more clear and complete as you proceed through this process.

Comment: @pmazzola - [Edit] your question instead of submitting unformatted commentary, information contained in a comment is subject to be removed, as being unnecessary and unhelpful since it’s not properly formatted.